# how to open a png file (' �PNG ') on the front end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, png

I managed to create base64 file in backend with function:
for (x, y, w, h) on and y:
frame=put_glass(glass, img, x, y, w, h)
res,glass1 = cv2.imencode(".JPEG",frame)
image = Image.fromarray(glass1)
buff = BytesIO()
picture.save(buff, format="JPEG")
new_image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
return(new_image_string)

however the base64 string is returning the photo in blue, I think it has to do with cv2.imshow, because when I call this method I use glass1 to display the image and not the frame

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by logging the contents of a binary PNG file to the browser console...

Comment: Generally speaking images via browser are best served via URL,  `<img src="/pic.png"/>` as this will take into caching etc.  But if this is not possible then a dataURI like the answer posted is your best option.

Answer (score 2):

Guess you are looking for something like this:

```
await api2.post('/glass1/', formData, headers)
  .then((response) => {
    const data = response.data
    return data.blob()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      const b64 = reader.result
      document.getElementById("img").src = b64;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(data)
  })
```

Comment: This will work if response is base64 encoded. The problem you get though if you just send file content through a stream is that you lose the file's meta content - chiefly the content's MIME type. Without a MIME type for the browser to know how to interpret the data, it's just random data.

Comment: I'm using open cv to edit the image, on the server I'm returning this way, in fastAPI docs I can see the image myself:                                                   
     @app.post("/glass2/")
def glass2(image: fastapi.UploadFile = fastapi.File(...)):
    file_path = _services.upload_image(image)
    im_png= _services.glass2(file_path)
    if file_path is None:
        return fastapi.HTTPException(status_code=409, detail="formato invalido")
    return StreamingResponse(io.BytesIO(im_png.tobytes()), media_type="image/png")

Comment: @ControlAltDel  Makes a good point, the browser might auto detect using magic numbers, but if you know this is a PNG, you could maybe just do -> `b64.replace('application/octet-stream', 'image/png');`  Or if the images could be JPG / PNG do the magic number check yourself using something like -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type

Comment: I managed to convert the image to base64, but it is bluish, when I give the local imshow the image appears in the right colors